# magento migration tool base table Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'live.livecore_store'

Tags: magento2-migration-tool

We are trying to migrate from magento 1.9.0.1 to magento 2.0.6 and during the migration process we encountered the following exception:

```
root@magento-4gb-ams2-01:/var/www/html/magento/bin# php ./magento migrate:settings /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.0.1/config.xml --verbose
[2017-07-06 20:52:01][INFO][mode: settings][stage: integrity check][step: Settings Step]: started
[2017-07-06 20:52:01][INFO][mode: settings][stage: integrity check][step: Stores Step]: started
33% [=========>------------------] Remaining Time: 1 sec


  [Zend_Db_Statement_Exception]
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'live.livecore_store' doesn't exist, query was: DESCRIBE `livecore_store`



Exception trace:
 () at /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235
 Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute() at /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:95
 Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->_execute() at /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement.php:303
 Zend_Db_Statement->execute() at /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php:480
 Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query() at /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:238
 Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query() at /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php:444
 Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_query() at /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php:499
 Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->query() at /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php:171
 Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->describeTable() at /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php:1525
 Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->describeTable() at /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/ResourceModel/Adapter/Mysql.php:69
 Migration\ResourceModel\Adapter\Mysql->getDocumentStructure() at /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/ResourceModel/AbstractResource.php:109
 Migration\ResourceModel\AbstractResource->getStructure() at /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/ResourceModel/AbstractResource.php:97
 Migration\ResourceModel\AbstractResource->getDocument() at /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Step/Stores/Integrity.php:63
 Migration\Step\Stores\Integrity->perform() at /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Mode/AbstractMode.php:73
 Migration\Mode\AbstractMode->runStage() at /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Mode/Settings.php:54
 Migration\Mode\Settings->runIntegrity() at /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Mode/Settings.php:28
 Migration\Mode\Settings->run() at /var/www/html/magento/var/generation/Migration/Mode/Settings/Proxy.php:95
 Migration\Mode\Settings\Proxy->run() at /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Console/MigrateSettingsCommand.php:51
 Migration\Console\MigrateSettingsCommand->execute() at /var/www/html/magento/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:257
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /var/www/html/magento/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:874
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /var/www/html/magento/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:195
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php:49
 Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun() at /var/www/html/magento/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:126
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /var/www/html/magento/bin/magento:25





  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'live.livecore_store' doesn't exist



Exception trace:
 () at /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
 PDOStatement->execute() at /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
 Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute() at /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:95
 Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->_execute() at /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement.php:303
 Zend_Db_Statement->execute() at /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php:480
 Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query() at /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:238
 Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query() at /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php:444
 Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_query() at /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php:499
 Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->query() at /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php:171
 Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->describeTable() at /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php:1525
 Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->describeTable() at /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/ResourceModel/Adapter/Mysql.php:69
 Migration\ResourceModel\Adapter\Mysql->getDocumentStructure() at /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/ResourceModel/AbstractResource.php:109
 Migration\ResourceModel\AbstractResource->getStructure() at /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/ResourceModel/AbstractResource.php:97
 Migration\ResourceModel\AbstractResource->getDocument() at /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Step/Stores/Integrity.php:63
 Migration\Step\Stores\Integrity->perform() at /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Mode/AbstractMode.php:73
 Migration\Mode\AbstractMode->runStage() at /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Mode/Settings.php:54
 Migration\Mode\Settings->runIntegrity() at /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Mode/Settings.php:28
 Migration\Mode\Settings->run() at /var/www/html/magento/var/generation/Migration/Mode/Settings/Proxy.php:95
 Migration\Mode\Settings\Proxy->run() at /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Console/MigrateSettingsCommand.php:51
 Migration\Console\MigrateSettingsCommand->execute() at /var/www/html/magento/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:257
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /var/www/html/magento/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:874
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /var/www/html/magento/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:195
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php:49
 Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun() at /var/www/html/magento/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:126
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /var/www/html/magento/bin/magento:25


migrate:settings [-r|--reset] config
```

Does anyone have a clue what to do next?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there may be a table prefix, or there is a bug in the migration tool which is causing the db name to be concatenated to the table name.